# OpenLayers 2 WMSGetFeatureInfo getfeatureinfo not selecting feature

Tags: openlayers

I have created a feature picker layer:

```
// Add Feature Picker
            featurePicker = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
                url: "http://server01:8080/geoserver/sf/wms",
                title: 'identify features on click',
                layers: [layer01,
                         layer02],
                queryVisible: true,
                output: 'features',
                infoFormat: 'application/json',
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.JSON
            });

            featurePicker.events.register("getfeatureinfo", this, showFeatureInfo);

            map.addControl(featurePicker);
            featurePicker.activate();
```

From one layer (layer01) it finds the feature but from the the other layer (layer02), it does not find the feature when I click on a feature.

It does fire the showFeatureInfo event when clicking on a feature from either layer:

```
function showFeatureInfo(e) {

            // Parse the features into an array
            selectedFeaturesParse(e.features);
}
```

But no feature is returned when clicking a feature from layer02:

In another words jsonObject.features.length is always zero when clicking on a feature from layer02.  When clicking on a feature from layer01, jsonObject.features.length is equal to one:

```
function selectedFeaturesParse(jsonObject) {

            selectedFeatures = [];

            for (var i = 0 ; i < jsonObject.features.length; i++) {
...
}
```

I have the backend as geoserver and both layers are configured the same.  One layer is a table (layer01) and the other layer is a sql view query (layer02).  Why would the features not be found when clicking on a feature from layer02? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, which seems to be a bug.  You first define a layer with viewparams (in this case the query layer "layer02" had a paramater).  You then pass that layer to a new WMSGetFeatureInfo object:

```
// Add Feature Picker
            featurePicker = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
                url: "http://server01:8080/geoserver/sf/wms",
                title: 'identify features on click',
                layers: [layer01,
                         layer02],
...
```

Then here is the bug:  When the server call is done to get the feature info, it does not pass the viewparams back to the server! (Even though you already defined the parameter when creating the layer and passed the entire layer to WMSGetFeatureInfo, and actually you can see the parameter is there when debugging, but it does not make use of it)

Here is the workaround. (you have to define the parameters again when creating a WMSGetFeatureInfo object during the beforegetfeatureinfo event):

```
featurePicker.events.register("beforegetfeatureinfo", null, beforeGetFeatureInfo);
```

Then create the method to pass the viewparams parameter using vendorParams:

```
// This method is called by the picker to setup params
function beforeGetFeatureInfo(e)
{
  e.object.vendorParams = {  viewparams:"username:bob" };
}
```

NOTE: One thing that sucks about using this workaround is that no matter what layer feature you click on, it still passes the parameter back to the server.  In the above example, layer01 does not have a param but when the server call is made, it still passes the extra parameter to the server.  It works but something to be aware that you are sending garbage data to the server.  If someone knows how to setup an event to test for the clicked layer feature and depending which layer is sent to the server only pass the viewparams to the server when required and wants to show an example that would be great.  I just hate sending garbage data to the server.  In any case the above work-around works and returns the data from the server for any layer.